# Are mails from support@stackoverflow.com reply-able?

Tags: support, email

I submitted a support ticket via `/contact` and got an email from `support@stackoverflow.com` as a response. If I want to supply additional information about *that* support ticket, can I reply to that mail directly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, your email reply will be redirected back into our support system and attached to the *same* ticket automatically.

Incidentally, we have been consolidating all support tickets into one system, so depending on how you contacted us, a variety of different emails might appear in the response to you. It's not something you generally need to worry about — all emails are connected to the *same* system, and all of them connect back to your existing ticket when you reply.

Common e-mail address you might see:

- `support@` for generic support requests (this is the default if the support desk failed to determine what channel something came from, or if you direct-emailed us)
- `community-support@` for community tickets, generally via the /contact form
- `talent-support@` for Talent-related tickets, usually via direct email, but sometimes manually changed to match the request
- `teams-support@` for Teams-related tickets
- `team@` and `community@` are still connected to the system but are not actively used for outgoing support emails anymore

Comment: Thanks for the answer!