# What email domains are known to be used by Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, email

Stack Overflow (the company) and Stack Exchange (the network) may send emails to their users for various reasons, ranging from support to marketing. However, it seems that there are multiple email domains that are being used, and some of them seem suspicious at first glance—or even get marked as spam.

What *exact* email domains are confirmed to be legitimately used by Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 15):

These are email domains that are confirmed by Stack Exchange:

- `stackoverflow.email`: this is a domain for centralized email services across the entire Stack Exchange network, e.g. [account-related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301957), [features & announcements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338332), [research invitations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390557), [community digest, question subscriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362377), [inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379425).
- `stackoverflow.com`: [Support email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318072), Stack Overflow for Teams (current), Stack Overflow Careers (defunct).
- `stackexchange.com`: One-time email, [inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355566/241919), community milestones, ZenDesk support.
- `stackoverflowsolutions.com`: [Community swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358195), Stack Overflow for Teams (past).
- `firehydrant.io`: updates from [Stack Status](https://www.stackstatus.net/).

Comment: First revision: the email domains were collected by browsing my own email inbox, then cross-checking with posts on meta. Some of them might be outdated but I can't confirm without further research. As always, this post is free to edit and modify.